# Cadastrar dados passando por View diferentes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Sou iniciantes em asp net mvc e gostaria de saber como posso cadastrar dados de uma entidade passando por View diferentes de um mesmo Controller

Obrigado !!

Comment: Você quis dizer, passando por *Actions* de um mesmo *Controller*, certo? *Controllers* não possuem *Views*. Qual o objetivo disso?

Comment: Acredito que sim... Como uma entidade tem muitos atributos, quero separar o cadastro desses atributos em Wiews diferentes...

Comment: Você está usando Bootstrap?

Comment: Estou sim @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O caminho para formulários muito longos [é usando *tabs*](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-tabs). A *View* pode ter vários campos e o usuário vai preenchendo cada aba com os campos categorizados.

Há também o [jQuery Steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/), se quiser fazer com cara de Wizard. [Tem NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Steps/).